# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost::3306/gestionpersonnel?serverTimezone=UTC

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc

I have a problem with JDBC, I try to connect my java project to a MySQL database, and I get this error:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost::3306/gestionpersonnel?serverTimezone=UTC

Comment: Did you add MySQL driver dependency?

Comment: Do you really have a double colon in your URL? Because it should be `localhost:3306`, not `localhost::3306`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to have the mysql driver (jar libs) on your classpath -

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-installing.html and select based on you setup

Comment: thank you , I resolved this problem and now i have another one :com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Comment: yes , problem solved ! please telle me i am using java/javafx to build a desktop app can I just use xampp for my database